# slide back to previous page programmatically

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to slide back to the previous page within a javascript function (android/HTML5 project). I can get back to the previous page through `history.back()`, however, this code will not slide back.

Is it possible to make it do the sliding as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Swipe solution

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ru3D3/

```
$(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', 'article', function(event){    
    var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('article[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
    }     
});

$(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight', 'article', function(event){      
    history.back();
    return false;
    event.handled = true;
});
```

This code is used to go back to previous page:

```
history.back();
return false;
```

In this line:

```
$(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight'
```

**.off(..)** is used to prevent multiple swipe event binding during the page transitions. If you have more questions do not hesitate to ask.

## Button solution:

Working example also here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ru3D3/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[ data-role="page"]', function(){  
    $(document).off('click touchStart').on('click touchStart', '#slide-back-btn', function(){       
        history.back();
        return false;       
    });    
});
```

Comment: setting `$.mobile.changePage("../myPage#myTag", { transition: 'slide', reverse: true });`did the trick